# Freeze Table header or enable scrollable body in Jasper HTML table

Tags: jasper-reports

The Header should be seen when user scrolls down the table data.

I have gone through a lot of CSS code to try to freeze the table header but not been successful. Mainly due to my limited inexperience in UI. Generic solutions are not working in below code.

The table header shows up without any thead and the data is without tbody tags. I am not sure how to insert any div tag. Thank you in advance

Below is some existing CSS

```
.report-wrapper table,
.report-wrapper table span  { color: #333333 !important; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif, Arial, sans-serif !important; position: relative;}

.report-wrapper table.jrPage .jrcolHeader,
.report-wrapper table.jrPage .jrcel {}
.report-wrapper table.jrPage th,
.report-wrapper table.jrPage td { border-color:#DDDDDD !important;}

.report-wrapper table.jrPage td {
  background: #FFFFFF !important;
  padding:15px !important;
}

.report-wrapper table.jrPage .jrcolHeader,
.report-wrapper table.jrPage th {background: #abffa5 !important; padding:15px;}

.report-wrapper table.jrPage img    { margin-bottom: 20px; }

.report-wrapper table.jrPage .jrcolHeader span,
.report-wrapper table.jrPage span   {font-size:13px !important; color:#333333;}
```

Below is my Jasper Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-13T14:56:39 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="360FeedbackJasper" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b2b320e6-05ba-442a-ae37-11e094fd08f1">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="360feedbackAdapter"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="DM_STYLE">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{dmScore}.equals("12")]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#292323" backcolor="#D91511"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="table1dataset" uuid="d9e6ff71-23d5-4eb7-b8ef-fcd1bc653360">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="360feedbackAdapter"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="dmScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dmScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="shScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[shScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="selfScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[selfScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="maxScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[maxScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="avgScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[avgScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="peScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[peScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="mergeScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mergeScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="drScore" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[drScore]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="driver" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[driver]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="ques" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ques]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="OTHERS" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="OTHERS_VALUE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="SHOWDM" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SHOWDR" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SHOWPE" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SHOWSH" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SHOWOT" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SHOWAVG" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="DM_STYLE_PARAM" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["RED"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="overAllSummaryReportWithOthers" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[overAllSummaryReportWithOthers]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dmScore" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dmScore]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <band height="261">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement style="DM_STYLE" x="4" y="130" width="554" height="80" uuid="a9101195-3ec3-4fcd-acdd-f4f0665b9c5b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="table1dataset" uuid="360bff8e-005d-461c-a00f-2c990a894735">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{overAllSummaryReportWithOthers})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="154" uuid="0b4b40f3-54c6-462a-90a4-d8f32a62be93">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="154" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="a3280d8e-c3ff-4972-91eb-6e8da7f866ee"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[driver]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="154" height="30" uuid="12ab2c78-afbb-4db5-9a01-16b28cf3d9fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{driver}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="8d57520d-e982-430a-afd3-4121f4bd4600">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="d7a9ad1e-09b5-4791-8bd4-ca37e904fd51"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[maxScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="d339341c-b0ca-4482-b0ca-651be075fe60"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{maxScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="1a391443-bc9c-4be0-86cb-a3b8dec388f4">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="9c73ca1a-1521-48aa-b905-2ecfeb075cbe"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[selfScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="eced711e-cca2-4fd3-9d2c-46dd4787fe7d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{selfScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="269e656a-93bf-4f52-bcd1-b3e1c1a6436e">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWDM})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="26a14484-4368-4cce-b6cf-c9a4280abe0c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[dmScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="DM_STYLE" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="d43d838c-4eb7-4dd0-8afb-d7a4590dabff"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dmScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="347a38dd-a69f-446a-92ab-3ed4502cbad6">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWDR})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="ef3a228b-47f3-461c-a2c8-88c16eca5049"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[drScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="a834e7b5-7413-442b-9f8e-aee67590bede"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{drScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="20c307cd-1e54-4a42-8cc4-1540da53cc57">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWPE})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="a45e2224-b314-4519-aac4-e1e14500071e"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[peScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="c0d60f60-20b6-414f-9c5e-9b5033386d5f"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{peScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="0e710e32-ff08-4ce4-96c3-b505e3ecb3ed">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWSH})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="6eb72492-9b2a-4822-b306-903c220c40c1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[shScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="dff321ae-a25f-4224-94a6-096bcc232ce1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{shScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="fb2ee2a9-3156-42a1-95ee-aa35fe630fc5">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWOT})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="48bee6a2-8f4b-4280-9fa0-24a2dad19c06"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[mergeScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="72b1c817-d6be-470d-8243-514e77b67d26"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mergeScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="f292fb3e-0f95-4e24-8d27-763d15f390af">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{SHOWAVG})]]></printWhenExpression>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="50">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="027dbe79-5e7c-47ec-a658-5c4a1bd53699"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[avgScore]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="c7ac4bbb-1543-4d48-a524-0dc75fc0e6b5"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{avgScore}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="50" width="225" height="20" uuid="5c083db9-dcc4-48e4-b72d-764490baaf03"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Detailed Bahavior-wise Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="91" width="100" height="30" uuid="30a8aeab-8307-42e6-b375-da90350b6790"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{DM_STYLE_PARAM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What output format are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @AlexK - The data is being displayed as HTML table. I need to find a way to freeze the header row so that the header row is always visible as user scrolls down the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: sticky` CSS property to your table header style. Unfortunately, it seem the Jasper html exporter does not use `theader` or `tr`, and inlines all styles. Looking at generated table in my case:

```
<table class="jrPage">
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>Actual column header</tr>
```

hence, in generated html, set sticky property to `td` elements in 3rd `tr` element

```
table.jrPage tr:nth-child(3)>td {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way by trial and error. Hope this helps someone else:

In the css add these to existing tags:

```
.report-wrapper table.jrPage th {position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2;}
```

In the html file, I added

```
<div style="height: 500px;" ...
```